# On mouse over show information

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a list of items like here in stackoverflow list of question. For every item's owner name is a link clicking on which it navigates to the the profile page(like in stackoverflow also). But my current requirement is that on mouse over the link I have to show a popup(like in facebook) with some information of that person. So how do this?

Comment: pretty easily. hook into the hover event using javascript, and show a modal popup - something like the jqModal plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a **Tooltip** to display the extra information.

There are a number of these available, here's [15 of them](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/) to get you started.

Comment: 15 tooltip plugins should be enough for anyone.

Comment: But the display content I have to retrieve from the database how I will do this?